# fixed format number in java. (how to cut a number?)

Tags: java

I have writed this piece of code in java:

```
String[] tokens = strLine.split(delims);
SimpleOrderRequest bet = new SimpleOrderRequest();
long Id = Long.parseLong(tokens[1].trim());
byte polarity =  Byte.parseByte(tokens[2].trim());
float price = Float.parseFloat(tokens[3].trim());
float stake = Float.parseFloat(tokens[4].trim());
bet.selectionId = Id;
bet.polarity = polarity;
bet.stake = new BigDecimal(stake) ;
bet.price = new BigDecimal(price) ;
```

Where tokens[1],tokens[2],tokens[3],tokens[4] are numbers in different formats. The problem is that i have to cut the numbers to the first digit after the comma in order to send the data to wsdl service. Namely, when the the string that i read is:

```
0.00426,    12955094,  1,    100.,   1.
0.00050,    12954726,  1,    100.,   1.
```

all works fine and bet.stake=1. and bet.price=100. But when the string is in the form:

```
0.00154,    13189533,  1,    2.10,   34.77
```

then bet.stake=34.770000457763671875 and bet.price=2.099999904632568359375 , and the wsdl service don't allow me to place the request, so i have to cut the number. Can i do this directly when i am parsing the numbers? if no what i have to do?

Comment: I'm trying to imagine why would someone make a WSDL that accepts a decimal number (as I'm assuming from the fact your stubs use `BigDecimals`), then reject most decimal numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `float` to represent currency values in the first place. Just use:

```
BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(tokens[3].trim());
```

(etc)

It looks like you've got the right data type within `SimpleOrderRequest` - so why would you introduce a *binary* floating point conversion?

It's important that you understand how binary floating point works - there are umpteen questions on Stack Overflow about it. Basically, you should normally use `float` and `double` for "natural" values such as height and weight, where magnitude is important but there's really no such thing as a precise value - and use `BigDecimal` for "artificial" values where you can certainly have *exactly* $1.10 for example.

Comment: always use the string argument constructor of BigDecimal to initialize values

Comment: @Barun: Well not necessarily *always* - but *usually*.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd recommend doing the rounding when printing the number using `String.format`, and working with the data with better precision before that. But since your stubs accept `BigDecimals`, you'll have to use [`setScale()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29):

```
bet.price = new BigDecimal(tokens[3].trim()).setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

(You should also heed Jon Skeet's recommendation to use `BigDecimal`s throughout, and do this rounding after you're done with any calculations.)